# Retrieve value of optional Artisan command option

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, laravel-artisan

Laravel version: 6.20.44

I have the following command with an optional date param:

`protected $signature = 'do-my-thing {--date?=}';`

I look to see if the option has been set:

`$dateToDoThing = $this->option('date');`

and if it set, I want to use the value:

```
if ($dateToDoThing) {
    // ... validate, create date from string format
    $now = Carbon::createFromFormat($dateFormat, $dateToDoThing);
} else {
    $now = Carbon::now();
}
```

So when I run the command, without adding a date, I get the following error:

> The "date" option does not exist.

I have instead tried using argument, but now I get:

> The "date" argument does not exist.

I thought by adding the `?` after the option in the method signature meant it was optional? I feel like I'm missing something quite obvious here, if anyone can point me in the direction I'd be most grateful.

Comment: Options (as the name suggests, though probably coincidentally) are always optional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolve the problem with an option, rather than an argument, by doing the following:

In the signature:

`protected $signature = 'do-my-thing {--date=}';`

In my method:

```
if (!$this->option('date')) {
    return CarbonImmutable::now('UTC');
}
```

I didn't need to add the question mark in the signature, because it is an 'option' it is always optional. Hope that helps someone else out there!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with optional argument instead of an option ?

This works for me:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class TestCommand extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'test:command {date?}';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Command description';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $date = $this->argument('date');

        $this->info($date);

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Note that when you are expecting an input and not an option you should use `$this->argument();`